# counter in loop /list/ count same vale if they are one after another (python)

Tags: python, loops, counter

The idea of the program is to count life time of some structures (count same structures which are one after another) but i have problem with implementing counter or enumerate function, I don't want to count number of all. I've tried do this many ways. Now I am stuck.

```
struct=[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1,] #input list of structures
list1=[] #list of lifetimes for struct 1

for i in range (0, len(struct)-1):
    a=struct[i-1]
    b=struct[i]
    c=struct[i+1]
    if a!=1 and b==1 and c!=1: # if it is one separated record
        list1.append(1)
    if a!=1 and b==1 and c==1: # for first record in sequence 
        list1.append('f')
    if a==1 and b==1 and c==1: # for middle record in sequence
        list1.append('m')
    if a==1 and b==1 and c!=1: # for last record in sequence 
        list1.append('l')

print (list1)
```

it gives me:     [1, 1, 'f', 'm', 'm', 'l', 'f', 'l']
could you give me any advise how to implement counter  ? 
 for example ['f', 'm', 'm', 'l] (firs/middle/middle/last) is given from [1, 1, 1, 1] from the list of structure so it's 4 records
to get [1, 1, 4, 2]

Sorry, for my non programming language, I am beginner in this field. 
I've search any similar questions but couldn't find.

Comment: Should all lines after `for i in range (0, len(struct)-1):` and before `print (list1)` be indented?

Comment: Why are you appending letters to your list if you want only numbers in the output?

Comment: Why are you appending, 'f', 'm', and 'l'? How are you expecting appending just 1, 'f', 'm', and 'l' to a list to give you a list that has a 2 and a 4 in it? And what is the meaning of [1, 1, 4, 2] with respect to this list anyway?

Comment: bad copy paste, they are all in for loop, if i clearly understand you

Comment: What are we counting?  None of this makes any sense.

Comment: a was appending letters to find if I can print out at least the duration of life time. because when i was utilizing counter i was gettin number of all present structures

Comment: I want to count the numer of 1 (structure1) but only in case when the are one after another)
my mistake, maybe my explanations are not so clear.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to explain why [1, 1, 4, 2] is your desired output from this list?

Comment: if we have [f, m, m, l] it gives us 4 records, [f,l] - 2 records

Comment: @jgritty He wants a list of group lengths for each group of consecutive `1`s in the list.

Comment: @augurar Exactly, that's what she want

Comment: Please don't use `struct` as namespace, this is a shadow name of Python builtin module

Comment: Ok, did't know. As a chemist I am using it as a basic word. Thank you for all advises! And being patient for my faux pas'es

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it something like this, you're looking for?

```
inlist = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1,]
#         1                 1        1--2--3--4     1--2
def lifetime(num):
    output = []
    count = 0
    for x in inlist:
        if x == num:
            count += 1
        else:
            if count != 0:
                output.append(count)
                count = 0
    if count != 0:
        output.append(count)

    print output

lifetime(1)
lifetime(2)
lifetime(3)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 4, 2]
[3, 1, 1]
[2, 1]
```

Comment: as @augurar said I need list of group lengths for each group of consecutive 1s in the list

Comment: YES! Thank you! Sorry for bothering in such a trivial case!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the list by value, then return the counts for each group with a given value:

```
from itertools import groupby

def ilen(iterable):
    """ Return the length of an iterable """
    return sum(1 for _ in iterable)

def lifetime(num, lst):
    """ Return a list of counts for each group of num in lst """
    return [ilen(g) for k, g in groupby(lst) if k==1]
```

Example:

```
>>> inlist = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1,]
>>> lifetime(1, inlist)
[1, 1, 4, 2]
```